# Form Recognizer SDK, analyze with custom model, file stream issue

Tags: c#, filestream, azure-cognitive-services, iformfile

When I'm trying to analyze a pdf document using `FileStream` from a local file, everything works fine.
But when I use a `IFormFile` and use method `OpenReadStream()` and pass that stream to the Analyze method for form analyzer, i get an exception. I also tried creating a new stream out of the `IFromFile` stream and that did not work either.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Working code:

```
using var stream = new FileStream("D:\\somefile.pdf", FileMode.Open);
var result = await _formRecognizerClient.AnalyzeWithCustomModelAsync(modelId, fileStream, "application/pdf");
```

Code I am trying to make work:

```
using var stream = file.OpenReadStream(); // file is an IFormFile
var result = await _formRecognizerClient.AnalyzeWithCustomModelAsync(modelId, stream , file.ContentType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for now, its not elegant but it works. I am of course very much looking for something better if anyone can help.

For now, I am creating a file, saving it and creating a `FileStream` out of it. Also works in docker as I'm testing using docker-compose

```
var iFormFileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
var stream = File.Create(string.Format("tempfilename.pdf", File.));
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
stream.CopyTo(stream);
stream.Close();

using var fileStream = new FileStream("tempfilename.pdf", FileMode.Open);
var result = await _formRecognizerClient.AnalyzeWithCustomModelAsync(modelId, fileStream, "application/pdf");
```